# Incorrect date format + guidelines for dealing with dates in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I've recently been transitioning from R to Python and have just been messing around with dates and how to manage them in Python. However, I ran into the following problem when attempting to parse through a list of dates.

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dat = pd.read_csv("viz2.csv")

myd = ['8/15/14', '8/16/14', '8/17/14', '8/18/14', '8/19/14', '8/20/14', '8/21/14', '8/22/14']

xdates = [datetime.strptime(str(myd), '%m/%d/%y') for date in myd]

plt.plot(xdates, dat["Avg_Polarity"])
```

The error I get is when I attempt to use the strptime method from the datetime module.

```
xdates = [datetime.strptime(str(myd), '%m/%d/%y') for date in myd]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-107-4a982c8d4090>", line 1, in <module>
    xdates = [datetime.strptime(str(myd), '%m/%d/%y') for date in myd]

  File "_strptime.pyc", line 325, in _strptime

ValueError: time data "['8/15/14', '8/16/14', '8/17/14', '8/18/14', '8/19/14', '8/20/14', '8/21/14', '8/22/14']" does not match format '%m/%d/%y'
```

a. Can anyone point out how the dates in my list don't match the format I specified.

b. Do you have any guidelines for dealing with dates when using Python for data analysis with Pandas, Numpy, Scipy, etc?

Comment: The dates in the list match, but you are passing the *whole list* as a string - try `str(date)` instead of `str(myd)`.

Comment: It loops through the list so it shouldn't be an issue...but in any case, the answer below has helped resolve the issue.

Comment: You loop through the list **then pass the whole list**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this statement, where you are converting to string the entire list and then trying to convert it to a datetime object, using `str(myd)`.

```
xdates = [datetime.strptime(str(myd), '%m/%d/%y') for date in myd]
```

Change it to the following instead:

```
xdates = [datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y') for date in myd]
```

Since the dates within the list are already strings, you don't need to again convert them using `str`.